# What's the use of `theme` in `context.getColor` ?

Tags: android, android-resources, android-theme

### Background

Starting from API 23, the small method of getting a color **[getColor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getColor(int))** (by just giving it the resource id) of the resources is deprecated:

[image]

Instead, we are told to use a method that includes a `Theme` parameter too:

> This method was deprecated in API level 23. Use getColor(int, Theme)
>   instead.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getColor(int, android.content.res.Resources.Theme)

### The problem

**[The docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getColor(int,%20android.content.res.Resources.Theme))** don't say much about the `theme`:

[image]

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getColor(int, android.content.res.Resources.Theme)

### What I've found

Searching over the Internet, all I could find is that we can use the support library to get the color :

```
ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.color_name);
```

This is a bit weird, because under the hood, it doesn't seem like it's doing anything with themes. Here's its code:

```
@ColorInt
    public static final int getColor(@NonNull Context context, @ColorRes int id) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            return context.getColor(id);
        } else {
            return context.getResources().getColor(id);
        }
    }
```

Looking at Context.getColor, I can see this:

[image]

So it seems to me it's using the theme of the activity?

### The questions

1. What's the purpose of the 'theme' parameter?
2. How is it used? Is there any sample/tutorial/article about it?
3. Why was the function deprecated anyway? It still seems safe to use for me...
4. What's the use of the support library function? How different is it from using the deprecated function?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**tl;dr**

- If **your min SDK is 23** you don't need the compat API for obtaining colors.
- If **you don't use theme attribute references in colors** and don't plan change, use `Context.getResources().getColor(int)` or `getColorStateList(int)` as you're used to. It's marked deprecated but functionally it's OK.
- If **you want to use theme attribute references in colors on API 23+ only**, use `ContextCompat.getColorStateList(Context, int)`.
- If **you use AppCompat and want to be able to use theme attribute references on all versions of Android**, use `AppCompatResources.getColorStateList(Context, int)`.

---

Starting API 23 `ColorStateList` can contain *theme attribute references*, the same thing that's allowed in `Drawable` since API 21.

Theme attributes are mostly used in color state lists obtained by `getColorStateList` method as opposed to `getColor` so I'll use that from now on. Most of what's mentioned applies to both variants.

Example:

**res/color/my_csl.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="?attr/colorControlHighlight" android:alpha="?android:disabledAlpha"/>
    <item android:color="?attr/colorControlHighlight"/>
</selector>
```

> What's the purpose of the 'theme' parameter?

Theme is required to resolve theme attributes. Resources itself is not aware of any theme. Theme is provided by a context.

```
context.getColorStateList(R.color.my_csl);
```

is essentially a shortcut to

```
context.getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.my_csl, context.getTheme());
```

Both of these methods are part of public API so both of them were backported:

```
ContextCompat.getColorStateList(context, R.color.my_csl);
ResourcesCompat.getColorStateList(context.getResources(), R.color.my_csl, context.getTheme());
```

> How is it used?

Typically it's as simple as this:

```
final int myColor = ContextCompat.getColorStateList(context, R.color.my_csl);
```

If you use AppCompat you might be better off with another option:

```
final int myColor = AppCompatResources.getColorStateList(context, R.color.my_csl);
```

Here's a comparison between these two options:

- `ContextCompat.getColorStateList`

  - Requires only `support-compat` support library
  - Backports only API - it will crash when trying to resolve theme attributes below API 23
- `AppCompatResources.getColorStateList`

  - Requires full `appcompat-v7` support library
  - Backports functionality - it will respect context theme even below API 23

`ResourcesCompat.getColorStateList(int, Theme)` is API (not functional) backport of `Resources.getColorStateList(int, Theme)` which is used internally by `Context.getColorStateList(int)` on API 23+. In everyday use you won't be needing this method.

> Why was the function deprecated anyway? It still seems safe to use for me...

The method was deprecated to migrate developers from the version that's not aware of themes to the theme-aware version of the method.

The theme-unaware method is still perfectly safe to use as long as you use it to obtain colors without theme attribute references, for example:

**res/values/colors.xml**

```
<resources>
    <color name="my_cint">#f00</color>
</resources>
```

can be safely obtained by

```
context.getResources().getColor(R.color.my_cint);
```

> What's the use of the support library function?

```
ContextCompat.getColorStateList(context, R.color.my_csl);
```

is literally this

```
public static final ColorStateList getColorStateList(Context context, @ColorRes int id) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        return context.getColorStateList(id);
    } else {
        return context.getResources().getColorStateList(id);
    }
}
```

The method exists so you don't have to write if-else everywhere. That's it.

On API 23+ it can use the context theme. Below API 23 it falls back to the old version that cannot resolve theme attributes.

`ResourcesCompat.getColorStateList(int, Theme)` looks and works similarly, it ignores theme attributes (crashes when you use them) below API 23.

`AppCompatResources.getColorStateList(Context, int)` will not crash and correctly resolve theme attributes on all versions of Android.

> What about `ResourcesCompat#getColorStateList`?

You won't typically need this method.

It's a layer of abstraction. It's telling you that to resolve a color you don't need any god-object, any `Context`. `Resources` is just enough to resolve a color. BUT for `Resources` to be able to resolve theme attributes you need to provide a `Theme`. The fact that a `Theme` can be obtained from a `Context` is of no concern to `Resources`. `Resources` doesn't disclose or care that it itself came from some `Context.getResources()`.

> Can you [...] update about `getColor` too?

`getColor` will resolve

- `<color>` resource as color integer
- `<selector>` color state list resource as color integer *of its default color*

`getColorStateList` will resolve

- `<color>` resource as `ColorStateList` with one color
- `<selector>` CSL resource as `ColorStateList` with specified colors

Use the one that's required by consumer API.

There is no `AppCompatResources.getColor(Context, int)` because there's little point in a color *resource* being defined as a theme attribute reference. If you ever need this `AppCompatResources.getColorStateList(Context, int).getDefaultColor()` is the functional equivalent.

`ContextCompat.getColor(Context, int)` and `ResourcesCompat.getColor(Resources, int, Theme)` exist because they mirror the framework API. Their practical usefulness, as described above, is debatable.

I recommend reading the discussion below to grasp some of the elusive subtle differences.

Comment: I was asking about `getColor`. not 'getColorStateList' . Or are they about the same?

Comment: Pretty much, yes. I used getColorStateList to better show the example, a typical use case.

Comment: I should mention that there's an appcompat backport: AppCompatResources.getColorStateList(context, R.color.my_csl);

Comment: What's the difference between `AppCompatResources.getColorStateList` and `ContextCompat.getColorStateList` ? What's the difference between `getColorStateList` and `getColor` ? Can you please show an example of using `getColor` with theme?

Comment: AppCompatResources can leverage context theme and resolve theme attributes even below API 23. Absolutely, I'll update the answer later today.

Comment: So `ContextCompat.getColorStateList` can't ? It just uses the old method, ignoring the theme, while being able to cause a crash in case the resource has "?" inside, trying to access declared theme resources ?

Comment: Correct, that's what happens. The mindset behind it is that you'd use colors without theme attributes below API 23 and with theme attrs above while using the same method call. I love the appcompat version because you don't even need to provide different resources, you can just use theme resources safely everywhere.

Comment: I don't get then why the need for ContextCompat, if it has a better alternative... To prevent accidental usage of resources that depend on themes?!

Comment: 1. AppCompatResources didn't exist at first. Its responsibility is to *backport functionality*. 2. ContextCompat abstracts away the now deprecated method and you don't have to write if-else all over the place. Its responsibility is to *backport only API*.

Comment: backport functionality? But you wrote it will ignore it on older Android versions "ignores theme below API 23" . Don't you mean it will use it when available?

Comment: AppCompatResources backports functionality, uses theme on all versions of Android. ContextCompat backports only API, doesn't work with themes below API 23.

Comment: Oh wait, I missed the part of the class. You mentioned `ResourcesCompat#getColorStateList` too. So now I see 3 different methods? AppCompatResources somehow works on all Android versions, using the themes on all, while `ContextCompat.getColorStateList` can crash on old Android versions. What about `ResourcesCompat#getColorStateList`  ?

Comment: Ah, ResourcesCompat also just backports API in the same way as ContextCompat.

Comment: So... 2 useless functions that can crash , instead of just using `AppCompatResources.getColorStateList `?

Comment: Practically for most developers yes but it's never that simple. Imagine you don't or can't use appcompat library (it's quite big and on some projects it's not needed). Imagine you want to use theme attrs and you're OK with them being available on API 23+. Then you use ContextCompat. It has its uses.

Comment: ok, so why not have one function , instead of 2, that do the same thing...

Comment: ResourcesCompat.getColor takes *a* Resources and *a* Theme. Nobody says both of these have to come from one Context. ContextCompat.getColor is a shortcut. Both of these APIs can be used independently, both of them needed to be backported.

Comment: I see. Still quite confusing, especially because each is of a different class. Can you put a summary of each of them, and update about `getColor` too?

Comment: I totally agree. When I get to PC I'll improve it.

Comment: @androiddeveloper Alright, I've udpated the answer, look through it to see if everything is understandable now.

Comment: Yes, but how would you use just color, together with a theme? Is it even useful to do it? I mean, if there is a color that just references to something of the theme, why not use the "?" value itself, instead of the color...  Also, would 'AppCompatResources.getColorStateList(Context, int).getDefaultColor()" work on a simple color that uses something from the theme? If a simple color cannot have a reference to something of the theme, I don't get why it had to be deprecated. I think only Drawable and ColorStateList should have been this way.

Comment: `If a simple color cannot have a reference to something of the theme` I haven't tried (because I never needed it) it but it looks like it can. Plus if all you need is a color integer, you don't really care if it comes from a `<color>` or a `<selector>` or whatever. `getColorStateList` would add unnecessary complexity. It's about encapsulation, right? You just want a color integer you don't need to know that there's a `ColorStateList` class and that it has a `getDefaultColor` method. You don't need that or care about that in that moment. (But you as developer should generally know about it.)

Comment: Resource integer + theme: Well... It's the "correct" way with respect to separation of concerns. You don't need Context to resolve a color resource. You need Resources, color resource ID and Theme. But typically you obtain Resources and Theme from Context, so we've been provided shortcut methods. What looks useless for us, typical consumers of the API, is essential for other bits of the API, or perhaps some weird edge cases and optimizations.

Comment: Does 'AppCompatResources.getColorStateList(Context, int).getDefaultColor()' work on a normal color resource?

Comment: Can you please show an example of how to use the newer API (with the theme being set) ?

Comment: Hi, I believe I've answered all the questions fully. If you feel you need more information on a particular case, please ask a new SO question. Thanks.

Comment: It's not a question. It's about showing an example. I can't ask here a question "please show example"...

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean by "with the theme being set". I've explained that `Context` has a theme. **I've shown examples of how** and when to call each method. I've provided an example of a color resource using theme attributes. Put the pieces together. "What" is a [theme](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes) and how they work is out of the scope.

Comment: OK I think I missed something as I came back here after a long time. The function is `getColor(@ColorRes int id, @Nullable Theme theme)` and you showed something about `getColorStateList`. I guess they are the same, right? There are other ways to get themes, or just this way (via the Context instance) ? Does `getColorStateList.getDefaultColor` work on a normal color resource? Is it the same as using getColor ?

Comment: It's possible to create `ColorStateList` from a simple color resource. It's just as any other CSL, so yes, `getDefaultColor` works. *** Keep it simple, just use `Context`. If you need to apply a theme overlay use [`ContextThemeWrapper`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ContextThemeWrapper).

Comment: Suppose I do use the Theme parameter, what should be in the XML file of the theme?

Comment: The theme needs to define an attribute your drawable references. If your drawable uses `?colorControlNormal` your theme needs to have `<item name="colorControlNormal">`.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand. How would the Kotlin/Java code look like, and how would the XML look like?

Answer (score -1):

I use fragments a lot and by playing around this is what found.
First set up a context variable as follows:

```
private lateinit var  contextX: Context
```

then instantiate the context as follows:

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
contextX=requireContext() ......
```

then use contextX to get your color assigned to a view

```
binding.veeGroupId.setBackgroundColor(getColor(contextX,R.color.yellow_light))
```

this works fine. the required imports should automatically be generated by the system.

Import that make this work are, they should be loaded automatically but be careful when you select the prompts.

```
import android.content.Context
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.getColor
```

Comment: The question was about the extra parameter, of the theme...